# Draggable with hover and not

Tags: draggable

```
$(function() {
   $(".header-dialogue").hover(function() {
   $(".console").draggable();
});
});
```

The thing is to make block draggable only when the header is hovered. Now the whole block stays draggable even when the element is not hovered. How to perfom else function?
Example http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/LExPqR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery code to :

```
$(function() {
    $(".console").draggable({ handle: ".header-dialogue" });
});
```